# Is "too important a tool" a noun phrase?

Tags: phrases

> The reason is that state banks are ***too important a tool*** for the
>   government.

Do the words in bold form a noun phrase?

Answer (score 2):

The portion of the sentence in question is similar to the following:

> [ **a tool** ]<sub>NP</sub> that is [ **too important** [ **for the government** ]<sub>PP</sub> ]<sub>AdjP</sub>

But in your sentence, the adjective phrase ***too important*** modifies ***a tool*** directly.  It appears in attributive position, directly before the noun it modifies.  Perhaps surprisingly, this separates the adjective from its PP complement, ***for the government***.

An adjective modified by ***enough*** or ***to*** can be separated from its complement when the following conditions are met:

1. It takes a PP complement (like ***for the government***).
2. It modifies an indefinite noun phrase (such as ***a tool***).

In these conditions, the noun phrase can appear between the adjective and its complement.  Here's an example adapted from [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/):

> If a private company is run on the basis of maximizing profits, military protection could be
>   bought at [ [ **high enough** ]<sub>AdjP</sub> [ **a price** ]<sub>NP</sub> [ **to turn our forces against us** ]<sub>PP</sub> ]<sub>NP</sub> .

In this sentence:

1. The PP ***to turn our forces against us*** is the complement of the AdjP ***high enough***.
2. This AdjP ***high enough*** modifies the indefinite NP ***a price***.
3. All together, ***high enough a price to turn our forces against us*** forms a larger NP.

Your example is similar:

> The reason is that state banks are [ [ **too important** ]<sub>AdjP</sub> [ **a tool** ]<sub>NP</sub> [ **for the government** ]<sub>PP</sub> ]<sub>NP</sub> .

In this sentence:

1. The PP ***for the government*** is the complement of the AdjP ***too important***.
2. This AdjP ***too important*** modifies the indefinite NP ***a tool***.
3. All together, ***too important a tool for the government*** forms a larger NP.

So no, it is not a noun phrase.  But if you include the following words, it is.

---

NP　　 　noun phrase
　　PP　　 　preposition phrase
　　AdjP 　　adjective phrase